# Synchronize local database and live site database

Tags: php, mysql, synchronize

I have a local website in which user adds items to Mysql DB everyday. Now I want to make a live version of the site.

But instead of adding items to both databases, I want to only add to the local database. And sync the remote database.

Local site uses XAMPP. Also I don't think replication is the way I want to do it.

I'm looking more of a PHP way of doing this task.

Currently I have no idea on how to achieve this.

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: "I don't think replication is the way I want to do it"  What is your specific reasoning for thinking that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest way to do this would be with MySQL, but if you want to use strictly PHP, there're two ways to go about this if you want the live data to only reflect the local data (i.e. you're fine with deleting all data and re-pulling data). Because this solution is in PHP, **you will have to loop through each individual table**. You can run a PHP script that uses either PDO or MySQLi, but you will need one of two deletion strategies listed below:

1) `TRUNCATE` and `SELECT FROM` (Fast, but has **potential security risks**) This is a bigger risk because the MySQL permissions to `TRUNCATE` are `DROP` and `ALTER`. Not commands you want a regular database user to have access to. Here's the SQL to pull it off:

`TRUNCATE live_database_name.table_name`

`INSERT INTO live_database_name.table_name SELECT * FROM local_database_name.table_name`

2) `DELETE FROM` and `SELECT FROM` (**Slower the more data you have**, but safer). This solution is slower because you have to walk through each entry in a table rather than dropping and re-creating the table. However, `DELETE` is seen as a safer permission to give a database user as they can't `DROP` entire tables. Here's what you'll need to pull it off:

`DELETE FROM live_database_name.table_name`

`INSERT INTO live_database_name.table_name SELECT * FROM local_database_name.table_name`

Comment: I'm thinking of keeping a table in the local database for recording all the insert, update, delete actions on all tables, and then use this to take the backups and import into the remote database so that I won't have to empty the database everytime and insert everything again. Also I have images linked with every record so as time passes, I think it would not be a suitable way to TRUNCATE everytime. Any thoughts on this? or how to implement this?

Comment: You would need to compare each entry in the local database with each entry in the live one (which would be rather slow). Something that does a `SELECT * FROM local_database_name.table_name` and something that does `SELET * FROM live_database_name.table_name`. Then you could iterate through rows linking them by unique ID. Any that didn't exist in the live database or that were update, you could run SQL on the update from the two arrays in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to setup a replication scheme, why not just use (2 or 3) cron jobs, dump local / dump remote / update remote with local dump. And no, that isn't the best way to do this, but it works...

With just (2), dump local / update remote with local dump, run daily @ 1:00AM dump, and !:15AM update

```
0 1 * * * mysqldump --host="localhost" --user="user" --password="password" database_name > backup_name.sql

15 1 * * * mysql --host="remote_host" --user="user" --password="password" --port="3306" database_name < backup_name.sql
```

Comment: Local server is running on windows.